# Return all dates between multiple date ranges

Tags: php, date, range

I have tried to mix few php functions to get all dates between multiple date ranges.

First i used function:

```
public function getDatesForArray($id){
       return $this->sqlQuery("SELECT date_from, date_to FROM bn_prereservation WHERE 
       oid='".$id."' AND status='ACCEPT' ORDER BY date_from ASC");
}
```

to get all data ranges from my database. And i'm getting something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date_from] => 2016-12-05
        [date_to] => 2016-12-08
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date_from] => 2016-12-11
        [date_to] => 2016-12-13
    )
)
```

And next i used second function, wich should return all dates between this data ranges:

```
public function getReserv2($id){
      $dates = $this->getDatesforArray($id);
      $array = array();

      foreach($dates as list($start, $end)) {
            $format = 'Y-m-d'; 
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $realStart = new DateTime($start);
            $realEnd = new DateTime($end);
            $realEnd->add($interval);


            $period = new DatePeriod($realStart, $interval, ($realEnd));

            foreach($period as $date) { 
                 $array[] = $date->format($format); 
            }
      }
      return $array;
}
```

I expect, i get something like this:

```
2016-12-05
2016-12-06
2016-12-07
2016-12-08
2016-12-11
2016-12-12
2016-12-13
```

But i only get:

```
2016-12-13
2016-12-13
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `list` is the problem / mistake here. I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

> list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

You try to "extract" an associative array here:

```
foreach($dates as list($start, $end))
```

resulting in an **E_NOTICE Undefined Offset**
(I guess you've turned that off.)

So to solve your problem do that:

```
function getReserv2($id){
  $dates = $this->getDatesforArray($id);
  $array = array();

  foreach($dates as $d) {
     // print_r($d);
     // list($start, $end) = $d; // THIS WONT WORK
        $format = 'Y-m-d'; 
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $realStart = new DateTime($d['date_from']);  // get it directly from the array here
        $realEnd = new DateTime($d['date_to']);
        $realEnd->add($interval);

        $period = new DatePeriod($realStart, $interval, ($realEnd));

        foreach($period as $date) { 
             $array[] = $date->format($format); 
        }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

result:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-05"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-06"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-07"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-08"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-11"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-12"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2016-12-13"
}
```

Comment: For me it works after in $d.[ ] i used double quotes. For example $d.["date_from"]. But after i did this little change it works Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome! Yeah, it doesn't make any difference if you use double or single quotes there, I'm just used to singles there.